# Converting cell to structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, cell

I am trying to convert a cell into a structure:

```
A = {'p1', 10, 'ny'; 'p2', 12, 'nj'};
```

I would like a structure with 3 fields where

```
A.person = {'p1';'p2'}
A.age = [10;12]
A.state = {'ny', 'nj'}
```

I tried cell2struct but was getting in format I did not want.
I know I am missing something simple. Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean that is really important to have `person` field as a column cell array, while `state` field should be a row cell array?

Comment: You should modify your question to match the answer you chose. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with [`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html)? Let

```
>> fields = {'person','age','state'}; %// field names
```

You could use either of the following three versions:

```
>> S = cell2struct(A, fields, 2); %// fold 2nd dim into fields
S = 
2x1 struct array with fields:
    person
    age
    state
```

(gives a 2x1 struct array).

```
>> S = cell2struct(mat2cell(A.', ones(1,size(A,2))), fields, 1)
S = 
    person: {'p1'  'p2'}
       age: {[10]  [12]}
     state: {'ny'  'nj'}
```

(gives a 1x1 struct array, with a row cell array in each field).

```
>> S = cell2struct(mat2cell(A, size(A,1), ones(1,size(A,2))), fields, 2)
S = 
    person: {2x1 cell}
       age: {2x1 cell}
     state: {2x1 cell}
>> S.person
ans = 
    'p1'
    'p2'
```

(gives a 1x1 struct array, with a column cell array in each field)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I got this far, but it is not quite what I am looking for. This gives me a structure with 2 structures tucked within.  I just want one parent structure showing the three fields.  such that if I query S.aa I get vector [10; 12] vice ans = 10, ans = 12

Comment: @KeithD The second solution gives pretty much what you show. It is not that hard to post process it if required. For example like so: `S.age = vertcat(S.age{:})`

Comment: Sorry, time delay and hitting return posted comment when I really wanted to go to new line.  Anyway, the second suggestion is what I am looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that the result should have different arity depending on the field, one way would be starting from this:

```
A = {'p1', 10, 'ny'; 'p2', 12, 'nj'};
```

and continuing with this:

```
A = struct(                     ...
   'person', {A(:,1)},          ...
   'age',    cell2mat(A(:,2)),  ...
   'state',  {A(:,3)'}          ...
);
```